# CSS Orientation AND Sizing in one document

Tags: css

I am helping to style an app that is being built in Alpha Anywhere. The goal is to use `@media` tag to enable different styles to accommodate small phones in portrait orientation, large phones in portrait orientation, phones in landscape orientation, and Tablets.

My thought was to use `@media screen and...` to define ranges of sizes and have style code within it's brackets that define appropriate container and font sizes to make each format ideal for the device it will be shown on.

Because I'm working in Alpha Anywhere, there is a tab for the CSS.  I need to put all the CSS in this one location so I can't ref out to different .css file for each different style. My hope was to bracket the code for one style within one media range and the code for another style within another and so on.  Can I have multiple line/regions defined by their `@media` ranges?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 350px) and (orientation: portrait) {

/* Style Code for Small Phone Portrait Orientation Here */

}


@media screen and (min-width: 351px) and (max-width: 560px) and (orientation: portrait) {

/* Style Code for Large Phone Portrait Orientation Here */

}


@media screen and (max-width: 415px) and (orientation:landscape) {

/* Style Code for Phone Landscape Orientation Here */

}


@media screen and (min-width: 561px) {

/* Style Code for Tablet Here */

}
```

When I organize my style code like this it appears to be heeding only the style from the last of the 4 sets of code(tablet style).  Is there a way for me to style these different sizes/orientations on one page?

Comment: It will be almost impossible to target each device, you are better off targeting ranges and for phones you probably will only 2 -3 sets at most. As for your issue, please produce an example to show what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

[Start from mobile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Progressive/Responsive/Mobile_first) and write your default styles. Make small changes at the next breakpoint up, keeping it simple and only overriding what is necessary. Media queries for orientation will only complicate things, so use only `min-width`.

```
    /* Styles for default  */


    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
        /* Add styles for next size up */
    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 720px) {

        /* Add styles for next size up */

    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 960px) {

        /* Add styles for next size up */

    }
```